# Usage of therefore in a sentence - should I insert commas?

Tags: commas

Which one of the following sentences displays proper usage of commas?

> I am fascinated by your work and progress over the past year, and therefore would like to ask if we can set an interview in the near future.

OR

> I am fascinated by your work and progress over the past year and, therefore, would like to ask if we can set an interview in the near future.

Comment: Asked before at 'Proper use of comma before and after therefore' [closed] (for lack of signs of research).

Comment: How would you punctuate the sentence if _therefore_ weren't in it? I think you could make a case for a comma after "year" or for no comma at all (either way, we're talking about personal preference, not right vs. wrong). If you chose the version with the comma, I don't see any reason to add more punctuation if you choose to reinsert _therefore_ after the next word ("and"). On the other hand, if you went with no internal punctuation, the reintroduced _therefore_ might be one pause too many—in which case bookending it with commas is appropriate. Or you could omit all internal punctuation anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
I am fascinated by your work and progress over the past year; therefore, I
would like to ask if we can set (up) an interview in the near future.
```

I realize this is neither of the options, but it sounds much more connected and fluent by connecting two independent clauses through a semicolon.

Also, I inserted the word "up" in parenthesis after "set" as in to "set up" because I thought it sounded more natural.